# Integrating source-compiled package into ubuntu

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, intel, install-from-source

For performance reasons, I compiled GSL with icc (intel C compiler). 
I ran `./configure` with some flags, `make`, `make check` and `sudo checkinstall`.

I had to remove libgsl0ldbl, which is used by a number of packages (`bogofilter bogofilter-bdb ink-generator inkscape libgsl0ldbl octave-gsl octave-statistics octave-vrml pyxplot pyxplot-doc qtiplot`). I had to remove these packages, run checkinstall to install gsl from source. Then when I tried to install the packages back, they wanted to erase my version of gsl and install the pre-compiled one.

Is there any way to make those packages use the source-compiled version of gsl?

Answer (score 1):

I think to get the best performance, you'll want to also rebuild the applications with icc, and I'm not entirely sure that using a library built with icc and an application built with gcc will actually work.

But to answer the question as asked, there are basically two ways:

1. Rebuild a `libgsl0ldbl` package, using icc, with a different version suffix (or a different name but `Provides: libgsl0ldbl`), and install that, then install the packages which should no longer want the Ubuntu libgsl0.
2. Force installation of the application packages despite not having `libgs0ldbl` installed.  One crude way to accomplish this is `dpkg --force-deps octave-gsl*deb` on the deb file.